# Proper password for controlling a pi using RealVNC

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, vnc

I installed RealVNC on my ubuntu laptop. I log into the account I made with RealVNC. I enter the "team" I created. When I attempt to connect to the pi, it asks for a username and password. It supplies the username (coming from the laptop), but I don't know what password it requires. I tried the root password of the pi and the laptop. Not sure where to look.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried the username pi and password raspberry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the username and password of the **Pi**, never the laptop.

I can see two ways you could have gotten to this problem:

1. Did you try to login with the laptop's username and the Pi's password? That won't work - the laptop just transmits the login credentials directly to the Pi, which needs *its* username.
2. Maybe you changed the Pi's password and then forgot and used the old password?